# Xpath selector not working for (presumably) Ajax control

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select flights between 2 places on **[this](https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_IN.html)** travel website.

I am able to select the source (**LEAVING FROM** field), but having issues with destination (**GOING TO** field) input field.

**Here is the code:**

```
public class CathaypacificFlightSearch {
    static WebDriver driver=null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\bala back up\\personel\\selenium\\Jars\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_IN.html");


        WebElement leavingFrom=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='depart-label']"));
        leavingFrom.click();
        leavingFrom.sendKeys("Bengaluru"); // Entering the starting point

        WebElement cityList=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'ui-id')]//a"));
        System.out.println(cityList.getText());
        cityList.click();  // Selecting the required option

        WebElement goingTo=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='destination-label']"));
        goingTo.click();
        goingTo.sendKeys("Singapore");  //Entering the Destination point 

        WebElement gCityList=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'ui-id')]//a")); //THIS IS WHERE XPATH IS NOT WORKING 
        System.out.println(gCityList.getText()); 
        gCityList.click();
}}
```

I also tried using the below `xpath` and `cssSelector`, but no luck.

```
 //WebElement gCityList=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[id*='ui-id'] a"));
 //WebElement gCityList=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'ui-id')]//li//a"));
```

FYI, a similar kind of XPath worked for source field. Only having issues with selecting the destination city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

A few words about the solution:

1. You can consider to construct unique `xpath` like `//input[@id='depart-label']` instead of `//*[@id='depart-label']`
2. The `xpath` you constructed for `LEAVING FROM` as `//*[contains(@id,'ui-id')]//a` is **brittle** and **vulnerable**.
3. Here is the working code block which selects `GOING TO` as `Singapore`:

   ```
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class Q44982690_ajax 
   {

       static WebDriver driver=null;
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {

           System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
           driver=new FirefoxDriver();
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           driver.get("https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_IN.html");
           WebElement leavingFrom=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='depart-label']"));
           leavingFrom.click();
           leavingFrom.sendKeys("Bengaluru"); // Entering the starting point
           WebElement cityList=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'ui-id')]//a"));
           System.out.println(cityList.getText());
           cityList.click();  // Selecting the required option
           WebElement goingTo=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='destination-label']"));
           goingTo.click();
           goingTo.sendKeys("Singapore");  //Entering the Destination point 
           WebElement gCityList=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='destination-label']//following::ul[1]/li/a")); //THIS IS WHERE XPATH IS AGAIN WORKING 
           System.out.println(gCityList.getText()); 
           gCityList.click();
       }
   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, you have amazing techniques to improvise   xpath's... this is one Gray area which i have to work.. any suggestions or source which can help me! ??

Comment: hi,undoubtedly your solution worked well :).. any suggestion on improving xpath skills??

Comment: IMO, the best suggestion on improving xpath skills is to review others code, learn from it and implement it while helping others. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've loaded your test-case into my automation harness and I've seen your problem. You're logic was good, but your selectors strategy was your undoing.

You are using the `"//*[contains(@id,'ui-id')]//a"` XPath selector to target the **suggested city options** for each of your `<input>` field values (**Leaving from**/**Going to**).

It's working for `cityList`, but failing for `gCityList`. This is due to the fact you're selector will match both suggestions (even though your `cityList` one is now hidden). As you probably already know, in Selenium, if your selector matches multiple `WebElements`, it will click on the first one, in your case, on the `<li> <a>` of the departure (**Going from**) suggested options.

**Possible fixes:**

- **1.)** Make your city suggestion selectors more specific (I used CSS selectors):

  ```
  // for 'Departure'
  WebElement cityList=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.flight-depart li[id*='ui-id'] a"));
  System.out.println(cityList.getText());
  cityList.click();  // Selecting the required option

  // for 'Destiation'
  WebElement gCityList=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.flight-destination li[id*='ui-id'] a")); 
  System.out.println(gCityList.getText()); 
  gCityList.click();
  ```
- **2.)** Make use of the `.sendKeys()` method:

  ```
  WebElement leavingFrom=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='depart-label']"));
  leavingFrom.click();
  leavingFrom.sendKeys("Bengaluru"); // Entering the starting point

  // Now we are performing a TAB, or Enter to auto-complete the departure
  leavingFrom.sendKeys(Keys.TAB) //, or leavingFrom.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)

  WebElement goingTo=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='destination-label']"));
  goingTo.click();
  goingTo.sendKeys("Singapore");  //Entering the Destination point

  // Now we are performing a 'Tab', or 'Enter' to auto-complete the destination
  goingTo.sendKeys(Keys.TAB) //, or goingTo.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
  ```

**Note:** This method (**2.**) is only going to be relevant if the value you're inserting into the **Departure**/**Destination** fields is unique (only one city returned), else it will auto-complete the first `city` in the list.

**Note2:** On a personal note, I would always go with the `.sendKeys()` method as it's way safer than clicking on dynamical ID `WebElements` populated in containers such as that drop-down list. Yet, if you want to stick with method **1.**, then you should add some **[Explicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)** to your `.click()`s.

Let me know if this helps you. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @iamdanchiv, Thanks for your time and suggestion. its really helpful sply method 2 note. In fact it was my option too. but some how it did not worked initially.thats where I opted for dynamic ID selection. Great tips.. keep it up